# Fresh install has no styles

Tags: magento2, install

I have just made a fresh magento 2.0 install. However, all styles and images seems to me missing. Can I fix this without reinstalling?

Demo: http://tiny.cc/80t27x

Thanks!

Comment: Back end all links are working

Comment: I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: Check your back end all images and link redirection is working or not

Comment: Theres no styling on backend either.. Links seems to kinda work, but everything looks pretty funny.

Comment: did u check the file permissions ? if on a Linux based machine, u would have to assign permission to your folder structure

Answer (score 1):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: This is an accepted answer recommending modifying a core file. This is wrong and no one should do this.

Answer (score 1):

if pub static has no css or not loading than download by command(in case incomplete pub>static)

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

> Note: proper folder file permission not implemented can cause this.
>   give proper permission

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Also make sure to enable [Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command from magento root folder.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will download the content perfectly in respective folders.